# Will horses spawn in old worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

With the update of horses I have a problem; I can't find any. Do you need to make a new world for the update or do all of my other already managed worlds automatically get updated with horses?

Comment: @fbueckert This is a specific question about horses, not terrain. Not *quite* a dupe.

Comment: @fredley The title sounds exactly like a dupe. I don't play Minecraft, but honestly, it really does seem like a dupe.  A new feature requires chunk generation, whether it's terrain or new animals.

Comment: @fbueckert As someone who *does* play Minecraft, since mob-spawning is different on a per-mob basis this is a valid question.

Comment: @fbueckert I agree with fredley - this is a completely valid question, and not a dupe of the one linked. Mob-spawning (this question) and structure generation (that question) are completely separate.

Comment: I'm on the fence as to whether this really is a dupe or not, but the solution is still basically the same: If you can't find any horses in existing chunks, then generate new chunks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Horses are spawned at chunk-generation, so they'll only spawn in newly generated chunks. In your existing game you'll have to explore new areas of the map to generate chunks and so have a chance of spawning horses.

Comment: I found some that spawned after chunk generation; it was a new chunk since the update, but after exploring and finding no horses, I built a small base and moved on. When I found horses and brought them back, there were donkeys waiting for me. I believe they spawn like other passive mobs: at chunk generation, and rarely afterward if the mob limit is not exceeded in that area.

Comment: Given Yamikuronue's answer, it seems that horses can spawn in plains long after they're generated.  So the question remains: is *new* terrain required, or might it happen in old terrain (example: if you kill off all the pigs, cows & mosquitos.)  I'd love to see a link to an official statement from Mojang on this one!

Comment: Yes, I believe this is incorrect.

Answer (score 15):

What I've seen says that they will spawn in existing chunks, but only if you kill everything in that chunk.

This is because there is a limit on the number of passive mobs in a chunk, and that limit is very quickly reached. By killing everything in an area, new passive mobs will start to spawn to fill the cap again, and some of them might be horses.

Comment: Thank you so much after killing all the darn chickens I got horses!  Nice Job!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, horses will spawn in old worlds (answer to question). I made my world in 1.5. I'm using 1.6.2 and I have found horses just by simply 'looking harder and further'. Killing everything in the chunk does not make mobs spawn necessarily. If you travel around 1000 blocks in a random direction you WILL find a small amount of horses. Travel further and you will find more horses. Horses are rare, so you just have to keep looking.

Comment: Please don't post an answer to reply to someone else's answer. That's not how Stack Exchange works. If you get 50 reputation you'll be able to comment anywhere.

Comment: I did answer their question.

Comment: You are a) replying to Cmr's answer re the killing of all animals and b) just repeating what fredley states in his answer.

Comment: No I haven't, and Cmr is wrong so someone needed to correct him.

Comment: @Jack Please do lay down the attitude. You should write answers in reply to the _question_, not _other answers._ See my edit.